# Matrix multiplication using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand the below algorithm for matrix multiplication using dynamic programming.

If `mi, j` is the minimum cost of evaluating the product `Mi × ... × Mj` then:

- mi, j = 0, if i = j, and
- mi, j = MIN, i ≤ k < j { mi,k + mk+1,j + ri-1rkrj }, if i < j.

Algorithm:

```
for i := 1 to n do
   mi,i := 0
for length := 1 to n-1 do
   for i := 1 to n-length do
      j := i + length
      mi,j = MINi≤k<j{mi,k + mk+1,j + ri-1rkrj}
```

Any clue on how it actually works or if somebody can point me to a good reference for it.

Comment: The code simply repeats the mathematical statement. So are you asking where the mathematical formula comes from?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm finds the lowest cost to multiply a chain of matrices.

Given a matrix `A` with `p` rows and `q` columns, and a matrix `B` with `q` rows and `r` columns, the standard matrix multiplication `A·B` takes `p*q*r` multiplications - for each of the `p×r` entries of the product, `q` multiplications between the elements of the corresponding row of `A` and the corresponding column of `B`.

Now, matrix multiplication is associative, so you can parenthesize the product

```
M_1 · M_2 · … · M_n
```

as you like, it will always yield the same result.

Now, let `r_0` be the number of rows of `M_1` and `r_i` the number of columns of `M_i` (which must also be the number of rows of `M_(i+1)` for the product to be defined).

Then `M_i · … · M_k` is an `r_(i-1)×r_k` matrix, and `M_(k+1) · … · M_j` is an `r_k×r_j` matrix. So if the product `M_i · … · M_j` is computed by first computing the products `M_i · … · M_k` and `M_(k+1) · … · M_j` and then multiplying the two resulting matrices, the total cost of the multiplication is

```
c_{i,k} + c_{k+1,j} + r_(i-1)×r_k×r_j
```

where `c_{i,k}` is the cost of the chosen way to compute `M_i · … · M_k` (and analogous for `c_{k+1,j}`).

Now, the minimal cost of evaluating `M_i · … · M_j` by splitting after `M_k` is then obviously achieved if the two sub-products are evaluated with minimal cost.

And the minimal cost of evaluating `M_i · … · M_j` is found by computing the minimal costs for all possible splits, so

```
m_{i,j} = min { m_{i,k} + m_{k+1,j} + r_(i-1)×r_k×r_j : i <= k < j }
```

for `i < j`.

The minimal cost for the complete product is then computed by first computing the minimal costs for sub-products involving only two matrices [where there's only one possible split], then for sub-products using three matrices, for which we need the minimal costs for the sub-products of only two matrices - that's where parenthesizing comes into play, and usually makes a difference - then four etc. until the minimal cost for the total computation is found.

To find the parenthesizing that yields the lowest cost, you can search the array of minimal costs tolocate the splitting that yields it [and then for the two sub-products, etc.], but it would be better to store the information of where to split for the minimal cost alongside the minimal cost in the `m` array.

Answer (score 0):

i dont like copy&paste, i'll keep it short and give in my own words:

the key point for this problem is: calculating A*B*C has only two possible ways: A*(B*C) or (A*B)*C. similarly, calculating A*B*C*D has only three ways: A*(B*C*D), (A*B)*(C*D), (A*B*C)*D. (note: (B*C*D) and (A*B*C) here is a sub problem and has already calculated before)

so, calculating M1*M2*...*Mn has n-1 possibilities: M1*(M2*M3*...*Mn), (M!*M2)*(M3*...*Mn), ... , (M1*M2*...*Mn-1)*Mn

that's what it comes in your given pseudo-code :)